# How to get returns/refund value from shopify api

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to calculate the total sales of orders overtime similar to shopify reports dashboard. I tried using the transactions api and calculated the total sales by subtracting the refund value from sale value but the value I calculated and the one in shopify reports dashboard seems different but when I tried subtracting the returns value in the shopify dashboard and sale value from the transactions api I got the same value as in shopify dashboard.

So where can I find the returns data in shopify api ? or How can I calculate the returns value through shopify api?

Answer (score 0):

For refund amount check [Order API](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/order#%5Bget%5D/admin/api/2021-10/orders/%7Border_id%7D.json) and Order object
You will find there field **refunds** that will contain **transactions** and **refund_line_items**.

I hope that will contain all information that will be required.